# Boto3 dont Delete object in S3 or Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to delete an object from S3, and tryed em DO Spaces too.
My code do the upload like a charm.

When i delete the object the response is CODE 204, but the file never delete. The first test i do made 24h and the file still in S3 and in Spaces too. Can someone help me or test the code?

Thanks

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError


client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    try:
        result = client.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        print(result)
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


def delete_from_aws(bucket_name, item_key):
    result = client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=item_key)
    print(result)
    return True
```

This is the response i get from S3.

{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'K3BW68X0PSD7M2Z0', 'HostId': 'o/dL7zixtNQStfxg2ENNdQvTf11vullraC6t8ZLeIA3esT/pQLwPgd0Gtn3SQYqWRVxYBHmDjjs=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'o/dL7zixtNQStfxg2ENNdQvTf11vullraC6t8ZLeIA3esT/pQLwPgd0Gtn3SQYqWRVxYBHmDjjs=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'K3BW68X0PSD7M2Z0', 'date': 'Mon, 30 Aug 2021 18:10:41 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Comment: You would also get 2xx response if you specify a valid bucket that you have access to but you specify the wrong key e.g. the key of a non-existent object. That will also report as success. So, check you are using the correct key (e.g. `cats/persian.png`).

Comment: Thanks, i found the error. I am getting the filename to delete from a txt file. And when i read the file and put it on a list its print the break line "\n" in the filename to delete. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @PedroIvoEuzébio Glad to know that you found a fix! If you don't think your question will help future readers, feel free to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would also get 2xx response if you specify a valid bucket that you have access to but you specify the wrong key e.g. the key of a non-existent object. That will also report as success.

Check you are using the correct key (e.g. `cats/persian.png`). Also, make sure that there are no extraneous, non-printable characters e.g. whitespace or newlines. One good way to do that is to print/log something like `"AAA" + filename + "BBB"` which will show you leading/trailing whitespace in a filename.